# How do I install MacOS Sierra DMG to Bootable USB?

Tags: mac, usb, startup

I have MacBook Pro (Mid 2012) model, and I formatted the whole hard-drive to create partitions on 500GB HDD. So now I don't have any OS installed on MacBook and for booting I use `Cmd+Opt+R` and It gives me "Internet Recovery" option. After that It prompts me "OS X Utilities". From there I choose "Re-install MacOS" and It gives me Yosemite installation.

The problem is, I don't want to install Yosemite, I want to install macOS Sierra but it is prompting me to download Yosemite. So I downloaded a **Install macOS Sierra.dmg** file from torrents and now I want to create a Bootable USB drive.

While searching for solutions on net, I found poeple are installing from "Install macOS Sierra**.app**", not from "**.dmg**" extension.

### Quesion

Please suggest me how would I create Bootable USB from **Install macOS Sierra.dmg**? I don't have "*.app" folder.

I have access to my other machines with MacOS and Ubuntu to make it happen.

Comment: If you have access to MacOS, why wouldn't you just download Sierra from the app store?

Comment: First of all, downloading OS X/macOS from a torrent is dangerous as it could be compromised, much less its not a legitimate way of obtaining the OS. Use Internet Recovery to install the offered OS and then upgrade it to the latest macOS through the App Store. Or Use Internet Recovery to install the offered OS and then download the macOS upgrade from the App Store, then create a USB Installer in the proper manner and then clean install it.

Comment: @Batman, I don't have any OS installed, I formatted the whole system to make clean install. So I have to use "Internet Recovery" or use "Bootable USB"

Comment: @user3439894, I understand that I can do using "Internet Recovery" but I don't have any stable network/wifi connection. I tried this last night but got interrupted twice and wasted my time and usage. So I would want to create a Bootable USB from *.dmg file. BTW, do you know why it Installs "Yosemite" not "Sierra" or "El Capitan"?

Comment: @user3439894, Suggest me if I can do "Internet Recovery" if my network connection drops multiple times? will it resume?

Comment: If you have someone near you with Macos Sierra, you can simply make a legitimate bootable drive via their terminal. I strongly advise against torrents, there are various privacy issues and Apple will no longer support you.

Comment: @MythicCocoa, Yes. I have access to Macs with Sierra installed. But In their "Applications" folder, There is not "Install MacOS Sierra.app" file. I think the installer deletes the *.app file after installtion.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what you need to do, you have two options:

1. Use Internet Recovery to install Yosemite, like you were doing earlier, and then either upgrade to macOS Sierra via the App Store or just download the macOS Sierra upgrade to create a macOS Sierra USB Installer from.
2. To create a macOS Sierra USB Installer you need a working Mac so you can download macOS Sierra from the App Store and with a blank USB stick run this command via Terminal. Make sure you first reformat the USB stick using Disk Utility to Mac OS X Extended (Journaled). **Also rename the USB stick to: Untitled**

   Use the following command:

   ```
   sudo /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Sierra.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/Untitled --applicationpath /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Sierra.app --nointeraction
   ```

   Then perform a clean install using the macOS Sierra USB Installer.

Comment: I don't wanna waste my internet usage and bandwidth so I am going for option 2. However I manage to get *.dmg file not *.app file. How do I convert *.dmg to *.app?

Comment: Follow these instructions https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201372

Comment: Let me check. Hold on.

Checked it, Its for *.app folder, not *.dmg... :(

Comment: Or use this software to create a USB installed https://macdaddy.io/install-disk-creator/

Comment: What I am trying to do now:
1. Convert *.dmg to *.iso via `dmg2img` utility
2. Using UNetBootin, I will create bootable of that ISO.

Hoping that it would work.

Comment: Good luck on that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59642/discussion-between-vs4vijay-and-maximus).

Comment: Converting a dmg to iso to then use Unetbootin is like trying to go from NYC to London by way of Sidney.  The easiest, most secure and reliable way to accomplish what you want is to follow the instructions by @Maximus in this answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you have "Install macOS Sierra.dmg", Install it and you will get the app "Install mac OS Sierra.app" installed on your applications folder.

So to be clear, installing "Install macOS Sierra.dmg" will not install Sierra OS on the current computer but only puts the "Install macOS Sierra" app inside the applications folder.

This way you get the app. And you create the bootable USB by running the command given by Maximus.

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

if you re-download the installer from app store you'r able to stop and resume your dl when is finished and prompt for rebot quit the installer, now you can find the installer on the Application folder, then follow the Maximus instructions